# How to convert PHP simple if statement to Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to set a random field like in PHP e.g. 1-3 and do the code for each state, however I do not know ho to do the same using javasccript. Is it possible, how to do such thing? Thanks in advance.

```
            <?php $random = rand(1,3); ?>

            <?php if ($random == 1) : ?> 
                <div id="myContent">
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($random == 2) : ?> 
                <div id="myContent2">
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if ($random == 3) : ?> 
                <div id="myContent3">
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// generate a random number between 1 and 3 (inclusive)
var rand=Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1

if (rand==1) {
  document.write("first content");
}

if (rand==2) {
  document.write("second content");
}

if (rand==3) {
  document.write("third content");
}
```

Comment: Also includes `0` for `rand`.

Comment: `rand` should be `Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1`. to get from 1-3.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest jQuery and the following combination:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="myContent1">
    <p>Alternative content 1</p>
</div>

<div id="myContent2">
    <p>Alternative content 2</p>
</div>

<div id="myContent3">
    <p>Alternative content 3</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#myContent1, #myContent2, #myContent3 {
    display: none;
}
```

**JS**:

1) add jQuery

2)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function randint(min, max) {
        var res;
        do {
           res = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        } while (res > max);
        return res;
    }
    var rnd = randint(1, 3);
    $('#myContent' + rnd).show();
</script>
```

**Sample fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uXfcx/**. Press Ctrl+Enter to run / re-run

Comment: BTW, not to belittle @Bluewind's answer, but anyway, it's highly **not** recommended using `document.write`

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your `while` loop? Won't `res` always be `<= max` after the assignment?

Comment: @pimvdb due to rounding errors it's possible (with tiny probability) that Math.random *could* be 1

Comment: That's interesting, because the specs say: `Returns a Number value with positive sign, greater than or equal to 0 but less than 1, ...`

Comment: Yes, it *should*, but it's using IEEE floating point format, and some edge cases are still possible, so it's alway better to put such an insurance.

Answer (score 1):

Trivial answer with some jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    switch(Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1){
         case 1: $('body').append('<div id="myContent1">Content 1</div>'); break;
         case 2: $('body').append('<div id="myContent2">Content 2</div>'); break;   
         case 3: $('body').append('<div id="myContent3">Content 3</div>'); break;
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*3) + 1;
switch(num) {
    case 1: // refactor me
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("id", "myContent" + num);
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        break;
    // etc
}
```

Pretty simple stuff and no jQuery :-)

Comment: Love this. Thank you for avoiding unnecessary libraries and document.write.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a function like:

```
function showRandomContent() {
    var randomNo=Math.floor(Math.random()*3)+1; //generates random number between 1 and 3

    switch (randomNo) {
        case 1:
            document.getElementById("MyContent").innerHTML = Content1;
            break;
        case 2:
            document.getElementById("MyContent").innerHTML = Content2;
            break;
        case 3:
            document.getElementById("MyContent").innerHTML = Content3;
            break;
    }
}
```

Now all you have to do is to include a div with id MyContent in your HTML

```
<div id="MyContent"></div>
```

The above function showRandomContent() will include the content based on the random number.